# convert 'n' row values to 'n' columns with one row in sql

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table like

```
ID ManfId
1   100
1   200
1   300
1   400
```

How can I convert the above table into the below in SQL

```
ID  ManfId1 ManfId2 ManfId3 ManfId4
1     100    200      300    400
```

Note : ManfId1 to MandId4 are new cols with new names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then manfid) as manfid1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then manfid) as manfid2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then manfid) as manfid3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then manfid) as manfid4       
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by manfid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: @Saideep . . . Then you would have a different question.  This answers the question that you asked here.  That said, you can use `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Comment: @Saideep . . . You should ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired reults.